# Pointing to host of a container to another one in docker networking

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I'm new to docker and trying out networking. I have an auth service in spring boot and mysql connection to it from mysql db. I have defined the mysql credentials to be picked up via env variables with application yml file like this

```
## application configuration
spring:
  application:
    name: ${APPLICATION_NAME:ignite-auth-service}
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:${MYSQL_PORT:3306}/auth_db?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
    username: ${MYSQL_USER:root}
    password: ${MYSQL_PWD:password}
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    initialization-mode: always
```

This is my docker-compose file. I have tried to reference the host of mysql service in the network in the auth container via the service name. This does not work as the connection is not established. Helps would be appreciated.

```
version: '3.8'

# services
services:
  # mysql container
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    networks:
      ignite:

  # auth service container
  auth:
    container_name: auth
    build:
      context: ../ignite_project_auth_service-
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8079:8079
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_HOST=mysql
      - MYSQL_PORT=3307
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PWD=password
    networks:
      ignite:

# network
networks:
  ignite:
```

Here is the failure logs from auth service when trying to connect to mysql

```
auth         | 2023-11-19 01:47:12.339  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: 
auth         | Unable to obtain connection from database (jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/auth_db?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true) for user 'root': Communications link failure
auth         | 
auth         | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
auth         | ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
auth         | SQL State  : 08S01
auth         | Error Code : 0
auth         | Message    : Communications link failure
auth         | 
auth         | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server
```

Comment: The `MSQL_PORT` is wrong, it should be `3306` instead of `3307`. The mapping specified is `<host-port>:<container-port>`, i.e. if we wanted to connect from the host to the container (e.g. with dbeaver or intelliJ), we would use this port.

Comment: hi, I appreciate your response. I still do have confusions about port mappings. anyway this does not change anything. same error. I have edited the original question with logs from auth service.

Comment: I might have found the partial solution. actually the auth service starts before mysql service fully up and running, thus connection is failing. but if I try to add restart on failure to auth container, then container keeps retrying and mysql never fully starts, but if auth container crashes then after some time mysql service fully starts. Any way how to fix this.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by adding health check monitoring on mysql service on dependent services